# python regex API pulling and converting to Text format giving error

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple python code to pull some malware feeds from open source api and find the only IP from this list .

The url already contains IP but when you capture it and save in local file you can see there are other string \r\n present after each IP may be because of new line.
Can some one pls guide as I am new to Python and what i am doing wrong here?

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re


url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/ip.txt'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
ip = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', resp)
malwareIPList = ip.read()
print (malwareIPlist)
```

> error
>   line 223, in findall
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
>   TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to `.read()` the `resp` from `urllib.request.urlopen`

Consider:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re


url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/ip.txt'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(resp)
```

Prints:

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x103a4ccf8>
```

What I think you are looking for is:

```
url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/ip.txt'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
ip = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', str(resp.read(), 'utf-8'))

print (ip)
```

Prints a bunch of IP addresses...

---

BTW, since the data are ip addresses delimited by `\r\n` you actually do not need a regex. You can do:

```
>>> str(resp.read(), 'utf-8').splitlines()
['103.14.120.121', '103.19.89.55', '103.224.212.222', '103.24.13.91', ...]
```

Comment: thanks alot Aurora, this works for me now.I was also trying to pull the feeds from

Comment: thanks alot Aurora, this works for me now.I was also trying to pull the feeds from http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/feeds/c2-dommasterlist.txt which is domains for malicious do you have any suggestion on this as well . I am trying to learn python but this part of API needs to be done at earliest. Appreciate if you Auro or any stack member can provide support on this code for domain gathering inside single string formatted by comma from http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/feeds/c2-dommasterlist.txt